# What does "input() already active" mean in python fileinput module?

Tags: python, file, input

I'm trying to read 2nd line in text.txt file:

```
import fileinput

x = 0
for line in fileinput.input([os.path.expandvars("$MYPATH/text.txt")]):
        if x < 3:
            x += 1
            if x == 2:
                mydate = line
fileinput.close()
print "mydate : ", mydate
```

But I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/tmpT8RvF_.py", line 4, in <module>
    for line in fileinput.input([os.path.expandvars("$MYPATH/text.txt")]):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/fileinput.py", line 102, in input
    raise RuntimeError, "input() already active"
RuntimeError: input() already active
```

What is wrong above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the second line from the `fileinput.input()` iterable, just call `.next()` twice:

```
finput = fileinput.input([os.path.expandvars("$MYPATH/text.txt")])
finput.next()  # skip first line
mydate = finput.next()  # store second line.
```

You can also use the [`itertools.islice()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) to select just the second line:

```
import itertools

finput = fileinput.input([os.path.expandvars("$MYPATH/text.txt")])
mydate = itertools.islice(finput.next(), 1, 2).next()  # store second line.
```

Both methods ensure that no more than two lines are ever read from the input.

The `.input()` function returns a global singleton object, that the other functions operate on. You can only run *one* `fileinput.input()` instance *at a time*. Make sure you called `fileinput.close()` before you open a new `input()` object.

You should use the `fileinput.FileInput()` class instead to create multiple instances.

Comment: The file is really huge, i need to read 2nd line only. Is your suggestion above sutiable for this?

Comment: I tried the first method, but I still get "input() already active" error.

Comment: @alwbtc: Both methods only read enough to give you the first two lines (using a read buffer). Neither method will read the whole file.

Comment: I tried fileinput.FileInput() instead of fileinput.input() and it worked.

Comment: OK, but I create only 1 instance if I use your first method, with fileinput.input(). Why do I still get "input() already active" error?

Comment: @alwbtc: No idea, but the error is *only* thrown when `input()` has been called once before but not closed.

Comment: But I had closed input() :(

Answer (score 1):

The python way is:

```
with open('text.txt', 'r') as file:
    file.next() #as Martjin stated in his response, skips 1st line
    mydate = file.next()
```

In this example only 2 lines are read from the file, and it's closed automatically.

For your exact question:
My python is Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Apr 16 2010, 13:57:41) and it doesn't raise that error for your example.That error would appear because you're not consuming all the lines before you reopen the input.

Comment: I don't want to consume all lines, text file is really huge.

Comment: I stated that only the 2 first lines are read from the file, the processing is always at most 2 lines, no matter the length of the file